# Using Keys Enumeration or Ascii code is better in-terms of good programming?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Please provide me view on below code.. on option 1 and option 2 to use for better programming practices in C#.

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{

    // Option 1
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter )
    {
        // some code
    }

    //Option 2
    if (e.KeyCode == (char)13)
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: This site isn't for code reviews, Try posting it here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: just asking better way  - of available options in terms of performance or good programming practice.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you would want to use Option 2? Is there anything special about the scenario you're working on? Because I honestly can't think of any reason to choose it over option 1.

Comment: `e.KeyCode == (char)75`, oh wait, let me alt+tab out VS to check this ASCII table... 75... 75... damn, where is it... oh found it, oh it is `K`!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about codereview which is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 that is `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)` is better:

1. It's *easier to read*, e.g. what's `(char) 27` or `(char) 9`? `Keys.Escape` is evident
2. Characters and keys are *not in one-to-one relation*, e.g. *character '1'* can be result from either `Keys.D1` or `Keys.NumPad1`

Answer (score 3):

Picture this: it's late at night and you are looking through this code, you get to that line, and wonder: what exactly does `13` mean? Is that 13 decimal, or 13 hexadecimal? What if it was 41 - what does that mean?

It all comes down to code maintainability - using a preset enumeration (especially when its already provided for you, no work required) is far more maintainable and readable than straight ASCII codes.

Sure, the ASCII codes work and they are old skool and bad ass, but the enumeration *reduces any chance of misunderstanding what was intended*.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that option 1 is more readable.
Use Enums whenever you can.

It is in general not a good practise to use numbers direct in your source code.

So if you have no enums at hand or do not want to create your own, instead of doing something like this:

```
if (myObject.Position.X > 25)
```

better do this:

```
int leftBorder = 13;
if (myObject.Position.X > leftBorder)
```

This might not seem so important at the first glance but as a developer you sometimes see code like this

```
mObj.SetVl = Global.iValue + 27 - (Global.uValue * 2);
```

Happy guessing what **27**, **2**, **iValue** etc means :).
It is important to give your variables meaningfull names and not to use lose numbers or strings etc. in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is cleaner and much easier to read. There is no reason why you'd want to cast the numeric value like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use option 1:

- It is cleaner
- It is easier to read
- It will still work if the numerical value should change at some point in the future.